# How to reference custom fields in a collection template

Tags: plone, dexterity

I am trying to create a custom collection template, which includes some of my custom fields.

This is what I have at the moment: https://gist.github.com/adrigen/06bdc88bda6e9cf20a44

But the error is: NameError: name 'resource_type' is not defined.

I know I need to define that variable, but I cant find the right place to do it. 
I tried
`<metal:block use-macro="context/standard_view/macros/entries"
              tal:define="
      resource_type context/resource_type; >`

And a few other places, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What am I understanding incorrectly?

Comment: Your pastie is gone... can you reference a new one? or make a gist on github.

Comment: have replaced with gist

Comment: You can define it in `<div class="icon" tal:define="...">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the definition to `<div class="icon" tal:define="...">` as per Mathias' suggestion.

Then got the error

```
Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'context/resource_type'>
Names:

{'container': <PloneSite at /hccrems>,
 'context': <Collection at /hccrems/our-products/our-products/hccrems-purchasable-products/products>,
 'default': <object object at 0xb72c66a8>,
 'here': <Collection at /hccrems/our-products/our-products/hccrems-purchasable-products/products>,
 'loop': {u'item': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.PathIterator object at 0xb3dacf6c>},
```

And noticed that 'context' refers to the collection while item is an object, so I changed it to `tal:define=" resource_type item/resource_type;`

And now it's good.